# How do I solve my problems with a paper faced outside corner bead coming loose?

Tags: drywall, corner-bead

I'm doing drywall work around where the outside corner of my tray ceiling vertical meets the regular ceiling. I bought paper-faced metal corner beads and spray adhesive thinking it would be quicker than nailing it up. I followed all the directions: I let the adhesive get tacky before installing the bead, firmly pressed the bead in place on the wall/ceiling, continued to press it to the wall/ceiling for the next few minutes, and then waited half an hour before the first coat of mud.

Now I've got a crack in the mud running the entire length of the bead, and the bead is "spongy" to the touch. If I push against it, it gives between 1/16-1/8" or so, and doesn't feel solid. I figure the crack is from the rather thick coat of mud I applied to make the corner square, but I don't think it should have that much give to it. Should I tear it out and use a nailed-in corner bead? Or will another coat of mud somehow fix the problem?

**EDIT:** I tried driving screws through the paper-faced corner bead, but the metal in it wasn't as thick as a regular one, and the screws tore right through. I ended up tearing it down and nailing up a regular corner bead. When I was removing the paper-faced one I discovered that some parts of the adhesive had stuck well enough to tear the paper on the drywall, while other parts weren't sticking at all. The only explanation I can come up with is that I didn't prep the surface well enough, although I did wipe it down before applying the adhesive.

Comment: Rip it down and start again... No shortcuts this time...

Comment: @Tester: Yeah, I figured that would be the correct solution. I just hoped there was a magical corner bead fixing solution somewhere out there.

Comment: You could try driving some screws in, but you would probably have to drive them through the joint compound so they had a good bite on the corner bead.  You might try that before starting over.

Comment: No magic.  Did you spray adhesive on both the edge and wall?  Hope so.  Next time let it dry at least an hour before mudding. Check the bond before you start putting on the mud.  You may be able to use some standard drywall screws and drive them through the corner and into framing if the separated part is not too large,  then another coat of mud.  Or start over!  Good luck

Comment: Mud should not be that soft after it has set. How long after the mudding did this crack appear? Hours? Days? Weeks? When you said it's still soft, and it cracked: it sounds like a thick layer of mud is still still shrinking as it dries. Or has it been set for a week?

Comment: @Ian: It was a void behind the bead that was causing the problem. It had pulled away from the wall (within 24 hours) as the mud dried.

Comment: spray adhesive? You thought wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rip it down and start again... No shortcuts this time...

*Comment converted to answer*

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the spray glue is for plastic/pvc corner beads, the paper is a mud on corner bead, when mudding seams and butt joints on drywall no glue is applied to the paper tape and never should be. get some Mid weight or green lid usg set the bead with that after it dries bed coat it after that dries,  then a thin finish coat of blue lid usg or a light weight compound.

- Wet mud applied over not totally dry mud cracks 99% of the time "shrinkage" needs to be complete.